# How many outposts are there and will they always be resetted when you are able to visit them again?

Tags: total-war-battles-kingdom

I am wondering how many different outposts there are. It seems to me that they all have different names and a certain topography in the beginning. But will I return to them after having visited a few other outposts in subsequent weeks or will they be lost forever? Or will I be able to visit these outposts again at some point in time but I have to start all over again?

I have been playing the game for about one month, now.